# Is it possible to access d3-shape's algorithm for curveMonotoneX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am drawing a line in d3 using curveMonotoneX

```
import React from 'react';
import { line, curveMonotoneX } from 'd3-shape';

export default function GradientLine(props) {
  const { points } = props;

  const lineGenerator = line()
    .curve(curveMonotoneX)
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y);

  const lineDefinition = lineGenerator(points);

  return <path d={lineDefinition} />
```

For the purposes of creating a tooltip that updates based on the current mouse position, I would like to derive the value of curveMonotoneX at a certain X position. Is this possible? I can supply X in terms of pixels or chart units, and would be happy with an answer in pixels or chart units.

The d3 documentation refers to [this paper](http://adsbit.harvard.edu//full/1990A%26A...239..443S/0000447.000.html) for the formula to calculate curveMonotoneX for a given set of points. Writing the algorithm myself is an option, but I think it's more of a last resort as it introduces potential bugs from the algorithms not matching up exactly, or d3's algorithm changing in the future.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the drawn path's attribute getPointAtLength(l) with a function that divides the line until you get the correct x value - see example https://bl.ocks.org/tomshanley/373640a6bc6f89293507550ae5629488

Comment: Woof. I think that is a great answer but the iterative nature of this approach makes me a little bit wary.

Comment: agree - it needed tweaking to be responsive to mouse movements, but it is agnostic to any curve generator, which is good

Comment: I wound up creating an issue in d3-shape, we'll see if it gets any traction: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time I do not believe it is possible to access D3's algorithm. I wrote a solver which matches D3's path generator except near the first and last data points. For my needs I was able to mask this issue by adding two extra points to the data set, one before and one after (both offscreen).

```
export class curveMonotoneSolver {
  /* Solver for the monotonic curve interpolation algorithm laid out in
  http://adsbit.harvard.edu//full/1990A%26A...239..443S/0000443.000.html
  Unfortunately I was not able to get the the curves do not match d3's path 
  generator around the boundary points, so I opted to implement the first
  set of solutions for boundary conditions enumerated in the paper,
  "define the unknown slope by the one-sided finite differences" (you can
  CTRL-F that sentence).  */

  constructor(controlPoints) {
    this.doPreCalculations(controlPoints);
  }

  update(controlPoints) {
    this.doPreCalculations(controlPoints);
  }

  doPreCalculations(controlPoints) {
    this.controlPoints = controlPoints.map((cp, i) => {
      const nextCP = controlPoints[i + 1];
      if (nextCP) {
        return {
          ...cp,
          h: nextCP.x - cp.x,
          s: (nextCP.y - cp.y) / (nextCP.x - cp.x),
        };
      }
      return cp;
    });

    this.controlPoints = this.controlPoints.map((cp, i) => ({
      ...cp,
      dy: this.getDY(cp, i),
    }));
  }

  getDY(cp, i) {
    const lastCP = this.controlPoints[i - 1];
    if (i === 0) return cp.s;
    if (i === this.controlPoints.length - 1) return lastCP.s;
    if (lastCP.s * cp.s <= 0) return 0;
    const p = (lastCP.s * cp.h + cp.s * lastCP.h) / (cp.h + lastCP.h);
    const comparitor = 2 * Math.min(Math.abs(cp.s), Math.abs(lastCP.s));
    if (Math.abs(p) > comparitor) {
      return 2 * Math.sign(cp.s) * Math.min(Math.abs(cp.s), Math.abs(lastCP.s));
    }
    return p;
  }

  solve(x) {
    if (x === null) return null;
    const startIndex = this.controlPoints.findIndex(cp => cp.x >= x) - 1;
    const startCP = this.controlPoints[startIndex];
    const endCP = this.controlPoints[startIndex + 1];
    const a = (startCP.dy + endCP.dy - 2 * startCP.s) / Math.pow(startCP.h, 2);
    const b = (3 * startCP.s - 2 * startCP.dy - endCP.dy) / startCP.h;
    const cubicComponent = a * Math.pow(x - startCP.x, 3);
    const squaredComponent = b * Math.pow(x - startCP.x, 2);
    const linearComponent = startCP.dy * (x - startCP.x);
    return cubicComponent + squaredComponent + linearComponent + startCP.y;
  }
}
```